# Out of memory while assigning matrix in sparse matrix

Tags: matlab

```
A = sparse(10, 10);
b = [2, 2; 4, 3; 5, 4]
b =
    2  2 
    4  3
    5  4
```

I would like to make A be:

```
A =
   (2, 2)    1
   (4, 3)    1
   (5, 4)    1
```

It seems that my problem is that I am getting:

```
A(b(:,1), b(:, 2)) = 1

A = 
(2, 2)   1
(4, 2)   1
(5, 2)   1
(2, 3)   1
(4, 3)   1
(5, 3)   1
(2, 4)   1
(4, 4)   1
(5, 4)   1
```

My problem is that I am assigning instead of `10` >>>> `1134890`

And instead of having `b` consist of 3 lines, it consists of ~`3M` lines. And the code collapses.

> Out of memory. Type HELP MEMORY for your options.

I am understand that my matrix is being built wrong and hence many more points are being added and causing this.

How to properly achieve the desired output ? thanks!

**EDIT**

`b` represents a text file I am reading from memory using: `importdata(pathToFile)`. And I can see `b` is being constructed correctly.

Comment: care to show the code that gives the error?

Comment: @AnderBiguri `A(b(:, 1), b(:, 2)) = 1`

Comment: It takes 8Mb in my PC. Still, that is not the best way of filling sparse matrices. Its better to fill them when created

Comment: @AnderBiguri could you elaborate ? And what could possibly be wrong that it fails on my machine and works on yours ?. How would you then go on an create that matrix from a `.txt` file that you know nothing of besides its format ?

Comment: [Read this](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/constructing-sparse-matrices.html). Filling a preallocated sparse matrix involves loads of operations, so the best way of creating sparse matrices is by giving the values in one go. Also, I havent tried yout b with 3M lines, but those are a lot of lines

Comment: @AnderBiguri thanks. I will look at it. Though I must have at the end an square matrix.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144360/discussion-between-tony-tannous-and-ander-biguri).

Comment: @AnderBiguri I edited my question. Found me error. If you could take a second look will help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are just filling your matrix wrongly.

fill and create it using

```
A=sparse(b(:,1),b(:,2),1,10,10);
```

If you can not avoid preallocating `A` (honestly, try not doing it), then you can fill it by:

```
index=sub2ind([10,10],b(:,1),b(:,2));
A(index)=1;
```

Comment: Indeed it did the trick! but I have to know the max number of b before passing it to A instead of 10. worked. thanks :)